# Problem connecting phpmyadmin with Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost, laravel-8

I am learning laravel and have created a project in my D drive where I also have laravel related files. now I want to to connect my laravel project with the mysql database through the phpmy admin of xampp which is in the c drive. how can I do that? My laravel project is in D drive but xampp is in c drive.

Comment: Your mysql server running at 127.0.0.1? Than just set it’s creditinals in env file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should know your local address, is it using localhost or 127.0.0.1. Then, just put localhost/phpmyadmin in your search bar and it will open phpmyadmin. You should create the database and the user in your phpmyadmin, but in case you wanted to use default user in phpmyadmin just use this in your .env file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306 (Change this if you have another port for phpmyadmin)
DB_DATABASE=yourdatabasename
DB_USERNAME=yourphpmyadminusername (Default is : root)
DB_PASSWORD=yourphpmyadminpassword (Default is : null/empty)
```

Then you'r good to go.